# EmptyJsonFileError when creating Expo Project (empty files)

Tags: node.js, json, react-native, expo

I'm attempting to create an Expo project using the command "npx create-expo-app AppName". The project is created, but all the files (gitignore, App.js, app.json, babel.config.js, package.json) are empty. None of the files have any content, and I'm encountering the following error in the terminal:

× Something went wrong while downloading and extracting the project files: Cannot parse an empty JSON string
EmptyJsonFileError: Cannot parse an empty JSON string

This is a completely new folder, and I haven't previously created any Expo projects in it. However, I have correctly installed Expo.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Expo version: 6.3.7
Node version: 16.20.0
NPM version: 8.19.4

I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling Node.js, NPM, NVM, Expo, and some React Native libraries. I have extensively searched for solutions on Google, Stack Overflow, YouTube, and even consulted ChatGPT, but it seems that no one else has encountered this specific error.

I need that to my school project :(